# Issuing a new token after expiration using Cakephp-jwt-auth [CakePHP 3]

Tags: php, api, authentication, cakephp, jwt

I have a CakePHP 3 API using the cakephp-jwt-auth plugin, at the moment my tokens expires each week, when the token expires the user as to log in again on my iOS App. I want to automatically create new tokens when they are expired using maybe a refresh token, but I can't find any information on how to do it in CakePHP with the plugin.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: if you want to re-generate the token after expire then why you need to set it for 1 week ?

Comment: This is just for a workaround, I'm waiting for a solution before changing it

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes it's possible in some condition, when user open apps ,you can refresh token by using old token. This way token will auto renew in each app open, or you can set certain time to refresh token using token.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `Token` manually with CakePHP, but how you will update the `token on iOS App`?

In the iOS APP, if the token expired you can resend the `login request` with **username and password** that you **stored in device memory**.

So automatically the token will get an update on the iOS device.